# How to use backreference to replace part of the string?

Tags: regex, vim

```
.*\t.*\t.*\t.*
```

I have a 4-column table with 3 tabs as above. How can I replace the 2nd and 3rd tabs as comma in vim? I was trying to use vim to do that, but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
:%s/\(\t.\{-}\)\@<=\t/,/g
```

It uses a look-behind match to find a previously occurring tab character on the line, so it will match all tabs except for the first, so it will replace the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. tab characters with commas. See `:help /\@<=` for help on the look-behind operator.

Another way, matching only the second and third tab of a line, and only lines with at least two tab characters, is to use a backreference `\1` to store and refer to the contents in between the tabs.

```
:%s/\t.\{-\}\zs\t\(.\{-}\)\t/,\1,/
```

This also uses `.\{-}`, which matches 0 or more characters, but is non-greedy (so it tries to match the smallest sequence possible and stays close to the beginning of the line) and also the `\zs` marker to only start the replacement at that part of the match (just before the second tab of the line.) Again, see Vim's help docs on search patterns for more details on all those.